# Is there a way to fix these Firefox caching issues?

Tags: windows-7, firefox

So the past few days on my work computer, I will visit Google a couple of times on Firefox and then boom I get the "The connection was reset" error.  The only way I can get back to Google is by clearing all cache and cookies.  Restarting computer and restarting the browser accomplishes nothing.  I can visit Google in all other browsers and they do not have this problem.  Anything within the google.com domain fails to load.  I haven't found a clear bug by Mozilla team for this, but something seems incredibly wrong here.  I only have the problem with the google.com domain.  I haven't changed anything in about:config.  The only plugin I use if Firebug and disabling it does not help.  My last option here seems to be re-installing or possibly creating a new profile, unless someone has a suggestion.  Google will sometimes come back without clearing out everything only to fail again later.  The only for sure way to get Google to come back is clearing all cache and cookies.  I think we can pretty much rule out network problems here due to the fact Google will load in all other browsers.

Comment: When the browser fails to load google.com, have you gone through and checked all the proxy settings? Verify that they are all correct next time that it does that. Connection Reset *is* a network issue, but since you can reach google through other browsers, it's clearly a very limited network issue. Perhaps it's setting up a selective proxy for google.com only and can't connect to that proxy? What happens if you type in `http://74.125.157.147` when google stops working?

Comment: Okay, having the problem with Twitter now.  The ip works the domain times out same as Google was.  I am specifically testing with all proxy settings turned off.  If I should be blaming this on the network admins, that's fine with me.

Comment: When it stops working, does `nslookup google.com` still work from the commandline?

Comment: yes nslookup works fine.